# How to pass variables to a method inside a fuction JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

My code looks like this:

```
var getData = function(section, sort) {
    var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/+' section '+/+' sort '+/1'
    req.get({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Client-Id xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }
    }, function(e, r, body) {
        var metadata = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(metadata.data.length);
    })
};
getData('hot', 'viral');
```

I'm sorry for the last part of the code, for some reason I couldn't make it better here.

My problem is that I wan't to firstly ask for search parameters(section, sort) and then use them in my url inside req.get method. Compiler gives me some:

```
 var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/+'section'+/+'sort'+/1';
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

I'm new to Node and JavaScript, please don't blame me. Thank You in advance!

Comment: You have the plus signs inside the strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/+' section '+/+' sort '+/1'
```

with

```
var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/' + section + '/' + sort + '/1';
```

Comment: Lol I'm such an idiot. Thank You very much! But it's still good to know that I was so close :D